# mysql error "unrecognized statement type. (near terminated by)"

Tags: mysql, import, load

I have mysql version 5.7.19
I am trying to run this:

```
load data infile 'C:\projects\v1.csv' into table ups terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' (company,ups_name,ups_ip,ups_mac,community,type_id,mdm_mac,ter_dir,td,cty,city,location,address,is_active,connected_device_name,connected_device_type,on_id,optical_node,inserted,updated);
```

But getting an error:

```
unrecognized statement type. (near terminated by)

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check 
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n' (company,ups_name,ups_ip,ups_mac,comm' at line 1
```

I checked and syntax is correct.
I cannot figure it out what is wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the documentation very closely](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) you can see that while `FIELDS` is optional, if you commit to using that option you must include that part:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\projects\v1.csv' INTO TABLE ups
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (company,ups_name,ups_ip,ups_mac,community,type_id,mdm_mac,ter_dir,td,cty,city,location,address,is_active,connected_device_name,connected_device_type,on_id,optical_node,inserted,updated);
```

Without that there's ambiguity as to what's being terminated, `FIELDS` or `LINES`, as both have a `TERMINATED BY` component.

So to be specific, the `{FIELDS | COLUMNS}` notation means *one of*, not optional.